# asp.net identity customizing profile with string filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, web, visual-studio-2013

I am using this GitHub repository: https://github.com/rustd/AspnetIdentitySample as a guide to asp.net identity.

Everything works well, however I want to allow each user to customize their profile - so they are provided with a list of certain sets of data that can be presented to the user and the user is able to choose what they want to see and what they don't.  When the user logs out then logs back in all of this is saved in the database for them, so they don't have to choose from the list again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? What don't you understand? Are you asking how to add properties/columns via EF? How to make an edit page? How to save changes?

Comment: Ok, so using that sample I mentioned I don't understand how to create properties (i.e. Item A presents A, Item B presents B, etc.), which the user can then pick and choose from.  So, if I only want to see Item A I can click on it and it will now be saved under my profile.

Comment: Your question is unclear, but it sounds like you want to add something like a `String Filter` property to the user.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I'm unclear how to do this.  And I apologize for the ambiguity, I was having a hard time explaining it.  I don't know how to do this, so that it saves for each user.